# "\\\\".replaceAll("\\\\", "\\") throws java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, string, replace, str-replace

The following code fragment in Java:

```
"\\\\".replaceAll("\\\\", "\\");
```

throws the exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

The [javadoc on replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) does include a caveat on the use of backslashes and recommends using **Matcher.replaceAll** or **Matcher.quoteReplacement**. Does anybody have a snippet on how to replace all occurrences of two backslashes in a string with a single backslash ?

#### clarification

The actual literal shown above is only an example, the actually string can have many occurrences of two consecutive backslashes in different places.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can simply do it with [`String#replace()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29): -

```
"\\\\".replace("\\\\", "\\")
```

---

[`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a `regex` as parameter. So, you would have to escape the `backslash` twice. Once for `Java` and then for `Regex`. So, the actual replacement using `replaceAll` would look like: -

```
"\\\\".replaceAll("\\\\\\\\", "\\\\")
```

But you don't really need a `replaceAll` here.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks! I didn't know I had to escape the `\\` characters twice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
"\\\\".replaceAll("\\{2}", "\\")
```

The first parameter to `replaceAll()` is a regular expression, and `{2}` indicates that exactly two occurrences of the char must be matched.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Matcher.replaeAll()` then you want something like this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\\\\\\\").matcher(input).replaceAll("\\\\");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have backslash in replacement string, it will be treated as escape character and the method will try to read the next character.That is why , it is throwing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.